# Selecting Payment Processor other than PayPal Pro shuts down Payment Processor setup window

Tags: payment-processor, paypal, backdrop

This seems like a fundamental question, but I have searched and not found anything similar. Please excuse me if I have missed it.

Having successfully used 'PayPal - website payments standard' as payment processor in CiviCRM/Drupal 7 for many years, I am having difficulty setting it up in CiviCRM/Backdrop instance. I wonder if someone might understand what is happening here: At very first setup instance, selecting anything but 'PayPal - website payments pro', including Dummy Payment Processor, simply closes the setup window and returns me to the (empty) Payment processor list.
PayPal - Website Payments Pro allows me to enter details and save that option (though client does not have a Pro account).

**Environment**:
Backdrop CMS 1.24.0
**MySQL Database**: MySQL, MariaDB, or equivalent version 5.5.5-10.4.20-MariaDB-1:10.4.20+maria~buster-log
**PHP Version**: 7.4.33
**Web server**: Apache/2.4.56 (Debian)
**CiviCRM** 5.58.1

[image: screenshot of Payment Processor setup window]

Answer (score 1):

Updated Backdrop to 1.24 and CiviCRM to 5.59.4 and all processors now available and work.

Comment: Good to hear it is resolved. Did you have the Admin UI extension enabled?  There was a problem with that producing similar behaviour that is fixed in the current version.

Comment: Thanks Aidan. It certainly is now and I don't remember activating it (I must be more diligent about logging my changes and when I do it).